# Double pay from game tournaments

Tags: the-sims-4

So I have been playing The Sims 4 for a few days now. Went with the gaming career, and making quite a lot of money with game tournaments and streaming.

Normally, you get 4.995 from the Hillock 2 game tournament. But now, all of a sudden, I keep getting double that. I have no clue why, but when I place first, I get 9.990. Every site says you should get 4.995, and I've been getting 4.995 until I started playing today.

Does anyone know why this might've happened?

Here you can see the 9.990 pop up just when I win it
[image: 9.900 earnings while winning game tournament]

**Update:**
Stream revenues seem to just have exploded as well, like 5-10 times more frequent donations. Maybe because I hit the 1 million mark of fans? I did just cross it. But not sure whether i had it before or not, maybe someone experienced the same?

I also finished second place just now, and got paid double the regular. 6.660 instead of 3.330.

**2nd Update:**
So apparently it has something to do with the pc I'm using. I have 2 of the same pc's but one of them is paying me double and the other isn't. Now I think I got one of them as a bonus for when I reached a certain point in my career and the other one I bought. But as far as I know I just bought one and I didn't notice i got a free one until I moved. (after this post.)

The only difference i could find so far between the 2 computers is the selling price, well and the fact that the really low selling price one pays me double for tournaments.

I just want to know why, there must be some reliable reason for this.

[image]

Comment: @king14nyr thanks for the edit! My English has worsened over the years it seems ;')

Comment: Hmm... the only thing I found about earning extra from tournaments is if you use the Motion Gaming rig, but in your picture, that doesn't seem to be the case... Quote from [a source](http://www.carls-sims-4-guide.com/skills/videogaming/): *Gaming Tournaments played on the Motion Gaming mat give out anywhere from double to 25% more than the normal game.* Interesting...

Comment: @king14nyr yup found that too. but I'm using the PC (Hillock II is not available on the motion gaming rig.) I also went the "fabulously wealthy" aspiration after I finished the "computer whiz" aspiration I thought maybe that had an influence, but I didn't complete it before this happened and the shrewd reward trait describes something different

Comment: yeah, only a couple are on the Motion Rig, and even if you were playing one of them, your screenshot clearly shows you on the PC... None of the traits/aspirations seem to explain anything about increasing revenue from this, either. I'm officially intrigued.

Comment: @king14nyr i have another sim in the household, if i don't figure out what it is i might just change her job to gamer as well and get her to a million fans. I highly suspect that as the trigger.

https://forums.thesims.com/en_US/discussion/790711/wow-gaming-livestreaming-equals-insane-payout-money-making

They suggest making big money after they break the 1 million mark. i'll keep you posted if i do ;')

Comment: @king14nyr so today i moved into another lot, have 2 desks with the gaming rigs on it. I got double from tournaments on the one computer, but not on the other... I thought it might've been because i had modded Hillock II on the one. so i modded it on the other but still i get double pay on the one computer, and normal pay on the other. So it has something to do with that specific computer but haven't figured out what yet. need to go to bed now ;') i'll update my post later

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is fairly simple and I hope i can help you out. By purchasing a computer in yor household it it saved in your cache. This is happening to pretty much every single Item in your game save. When you start a tournament it obtains the data of the specific computer you are playing on. In some rare cases it might happen that the file is being replaced (for example when the computer is being repared, moved or the game has changed it's state somehow. It does not really matter) and this is the important part for your issue: if an item in the cache is renewed/ replaced or whatever it is being copied first and the original data is removed. As you can already tell by the explanation: sometimes the original data is not removed causing the computer to be two times in the game cache resulting in double income. To keep it simple: It's a bug waiting to be abused :)

Comment: No offence, but this seems like a guess and a stretching one at that. Do you have any evidence that this is the cause or a reliable way to reproduce the results?
If it would be a problem with cached data then wouldn't the bug be gone after i restarted the game/my computer ?

Comment: I basically summarized what a german forum has discussed and what TheSimsSupply (the youtuber) answered me when I asked him on twitch about this issue (because he had the same thing happening) there has never been a response on the official sims forums so I guess callng it a bug is legit and the cache explanation seems pretty solid. Here is my speculation: the game might create 2 let's call them "files" even though they are not files but maybe lines of code or something for this computer. That would mean that even reloading the game would not solve it and if the object is moved, both filed are

Comment: Can you send me a link to the discussion? (i'm half german ^^)
I literally couldn't find anyone discussing this "issue". I wonder if one could reproduce it.

Comment: not sure where to find the post exactly but it was on this forums http://www.sims4ever.de/ quite recently. The user mentioned stumbling upon an english thread facing the same "issue". He might be talking about this question here. Also I'm not sure if the sims supply saves his streams on twitch or not bus I asked him during his roller coaster tycoon gameplay stream. He was like "oh yea i had this bug several times. I just accepted the extra money though" or something like that so i'm pretty sure that it's not a secret mechanic or something like that. If it was the game had a special response

Comment: This answer looks [citation needed] to me…